# How do I access a component via URL in React-Router 4 when the component is initially not rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hopefully the title makes sense.

My React app landing page is made up of three components - a header, a main content area, and then a list of products at the bottom. When a product is clicked, a list of categories is then rendered in a full screen view as a child of the product and the name of the product is appended to the URL.

Due to the amount of products I'm using, I'm initially only displaying six products from a sliced array. The next or previous six products are displayed by clicking buttons, which changes the slice values by changing the state. When I access the URL of one of the initial six products, i.e. myurl.com/prod1, it successfully routes. However, if I try to access the URL of one of the second batch of products, say myurl.com/prod7, then it will not route and leave me at the landing page.

What would be the correct way of handling this sort of structure?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code? Particularly how you set up routing and then how you are mapping your lists of products?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare previous route's pathname to active route's pathname on componentDidUpdate method and fetch data if there are any changes in the url.

for example;

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname){
        fetchData()
    }
}
```

P.S: You should import withRouter hoc from react-router-dom package to access to router props.